# TSQL convert comma separated list of numbers to comma separated list of names from another table

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table of report definitions that has a comma separated list of **column numbers** to be used. Then there is a table of column information. I need to get back a comma separated list of **column names** given a report ID:

```
create table #Reports (ID int, Title varchar(100), ColumnNumbers varchar(100))
insert #Reports values (1, 'My Report Title', '1,3')

create table #ReportColumnMaping (ColumnNumber int, ColumnName varchar(100))
insert #ReportColumnMaping values (1, 'Column1')
insert #ReportColumnMaping values (2, 'Column2')
insert #ReportColumnMaping values (3, 'Column3')
```

I need back the title and list of columns for report ID = 1, which uses Col1 & Col3:

```
'My Report Title', 'Column1, Column3'
```

I've done it in a sproc with dynamic SQL but I think it should be possible in a single statement involving recursive CTEs but can't get my head around it. Any examples much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, it probably has some functionality you don't need and it doesn't get you 100% there.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit] (@sep char(1), @source varchar(1000))
    RETURNS table
    AS
    RETURN (
        WITH Lines(LineNumber, BeginPos, EndPos) AS (
          SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @source)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT LineNumber + 1, EndPos + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @source, EndPos + 1)
          FROM Lines
          WHERE EndPos > 0
        )
        SELECT LineNumber,
          RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@source, BeginPos, CASE WHEN EndPos > 0 THEN EndPos-BeginPos ELSE 1000 END))) AS result
        FROM Lines
      )
```

Then...

```
SELECT r.Title, c.ColumnName
FROM #Reports r
    CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fnSplit](',', r.ColumnNumbers) s
    INNER JOIN #ReportColumnMaping c ON c.ColumnNumber = s.result
```